# How Can I save data from GUI to array

Tags: java, swing, function, events, user-interface

I need to create a java project for bank account for 100 clients with Id, name, Surname, and Deposit. However, I don't know how I can save data from GUI to arrays every time I press Save Button?

Comment: Well what have you tried? You'll need some appropriate object type with those properties, and you'll need to populate a new object from the UI...

Comment: How is the data being inputted? In a JTextField or differently?

Comment: Look up Model View Controller. You would want to make an object with the properties above in your model. Everytime the user enters something into the view, the controller would populate the model....

Comment: Are you trying to add a new account everytime you press the button? Or are you just trying to update an account balance?

Comment: I want to add a new account everytime I press the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "I want to add a new account everytime I press the button "

- You should have your `Account` class already with the necessary fields and getters and setters
- In your `GUI` class you should have a `List` `Map` of `Accounts`. Forget an array, as they aren't dynamic. I'd preferably go with a `Map` but if you don't understand `Map`, it's a little bit harder to explain, so I'll start you off with a `List`

  ```
  public class GUI extends JFrame {
      List<Account> accounts = new ArrayList<>();
  }
  ```
- Then in your `actionPerformed` of your button listener, just gather the data from whatever source you're getting it from, i.e. text fields, and populate the `Account` data, then add the new `Account` to the list

  ```
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       String name = nameTextFeild.getText();
       String surname = surTextField.getText();
       String id = idTextField.getText();

       Account account = new Account(name, surname, id);

       accounts.add(account);
  }
  ```